# woocommerce cart not working on variable product (no js error)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have developed a WooCommerce site, there are two themes for desktop and mobile. Desktop theme is perfect while in mobile theme add to cart is not showing up in variable product. There is NO JS ERROR in console, debug mode is activated in wp-config.php but that is not showing up any error.

All plugins are deactivated.

Here is an example link of variable product https://www.longhornvapor.com/shop/innokin-itaste-vv4-express-kit/

Help at your earliest.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Is there a way to view the mobile them from a desktop? Otherwise I can't look at it. If your mobile theme is overriding the `add-to-cart/variable.php` template` try temporarily disabling that.

Comment: @helgatheviking yes, I have activated mobile theme for now, check it from your desktop please.

Comment: The template markup looks ok. I can't read the script because it is minified, so I can only guess the problem is in here: `https://www.longhornvapor.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_mobile/js/add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=4.1` Have you customized this from WooCommerce's default? The select change event isn't firing. I would suggest using WooCommerce's script.

Comment: Thanks mate, the problem was that in footer.php "<?php wp_footer(); ?>" was missing. I have created a new theme, created files one by one. After debugging each line. I found that this line was missing :)